# Javascript Constraint API and fieldset tag

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm playing with the JavaScript Constraint API to understand how a form is validated and submitted.

After reading the documentation at W3C and writing some code there is one particular thing that I don't understand. Citing the documentation:

> A listed form-associated element is a candidate for constraint validation except when a condition has barred the element from constraint validation. (For example, an element is barred from constraint validation if it is an output or fieldset element.)"

I understand that a fieldset tag **should not be included**. But when I do `document.querySelectorAll(:invalid)` the output contains the fieldset tag in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari.

Output in Chrome: `[fieldset, input#email, input#telephone, input#name, textarea#message, item: function]`

Output Firefox: `[ <fieldset>, <input#email>, <input#telephone>, <input#name>, <textarea#message> ]`

Output Safari: `[<input required type=​"email" id=​"email" name=​"email" placeholder=​"Your email">​, 
<input required type=​"tel" pattern=​"\d+" id=​"telephone" namer=​"telephone" placeholder=​"Your telephone">​,<input required type=​"text" id=​"name" name=​"name" placeholder=​"Your name">​, 
<textarea required type=​"tel" id=​"message" name=​"message" placeholder=​"Your message">​​</textarea>​
]`

Can anyone explain me why the fieldsets are included?

Do I need to target the :invalid errors in a different way?

I am facing problems when I want to target to a specific :invalid error message.

Thanks.

UPDATE

I've been able to achieve my goals by using the willValidate property.

```
var invalid = form.querySelectorAll(':invalid');
  for(var i = 0; i < invalid.length;i++){
      if(invalid[i].willValidate){
          // do stuff
      }
  }
```

Comment: Does the fieldset go away if it's child elements are all valid?

Comment: Hi Halcyon, yes if all the child elements are valid the fieldset doesn't appear in the console.

Comment: Solved using the 'willValidate' property.